# How I change the Magento Connect Manager location

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to know how I can change the Magento Connect Manager url from

http://www.site.com/downloader/ to http://www.mysite.com/something-else-downloader/

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to keep the store domain (Base URL) the same, but have the downloader accessed from a different URL?  I'm trying to understand the practicality in doing this.

Comment: I want to change downloader to another name

Answer (score -1):

I just change the folder name in my frontend servers and everythink is working fine

Thanks

Comment: If you go by admin->sytem->Magento connect -> Magento connect manager then it will return 404 error. How did you?

Comment: If you read mu answer I changed the folder name only in my frontend servers, I have a 1 backend server that allow me to access the magento connect.

Answer (score -2):

You can also manage from .htaccess file.simple write bellow code into your .htaccess file. And make sure to rename your "downloader" folder to "customlink"(as you need).Nothing do any changes in any files in "customlink" folder.

RewriteEngine On 
RedirectMatch 301 /downloader/(.*) /customlink/$1

Comment: If I understand correctly, this cancels the whole reason to rename downloader - to reduce automated attack attempts on it.